# sumar dias a una fecha en concreto con java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Tengo una fecha en formato dia-mes-año 15-02-1981, me gustaría poder sumar dias a esa fecha.

Los ejemplos que he ido viendo, no se por que pero me suma meses no dias.

Estoy intentando el siguiente codigo.

```
Ffin="15-02-1981"; //Este seria el formato de la fecha que recibo de la variable
```

```js
let Ffin="15-02-1981";
fecha = new Date(Ffin);
entrega = new Date(Ffin);
dia = fecha.getDate(Ffin);
mes = fecha.getMonth()+1;// +1 porque los meses empiezan en 0
anio = fecha.getFullYear();
entrega.setDate(entrega.getDate(Ffin) +1 );

alert(entrega.getDate(Ffin) + "/" +
(entrega.getMonth(Ffin)+1) + "/" +
entrega.getFullYear(Ffin));
```

Siempre me suma al mes no al dia

Comment: Muestra el código que has intentado.  Y también ¿qué fecha ingresas y que resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: le fecha recibida por al fuincion date es año-mes-dia

Comment: una recomendacion, usa la libreria https://momentjs.com/  es lo mejor que existe para trabajar con date te facilita la vida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separe el problema en 2 funciones, 1 llamada `parseDate` mediante la cual pasas tu fecha con el formato que indicas y te devuelve una instancia de objeto de tipo `Date` valido, y la segunda `sumDays` es la encargada de sumarle n dias a una fecha que le pases como primer parametro. Como tu formato es dia-mes-año y para parsearlo correctamente a Date debe ser al menos como una de las variantes mes/dia/año, convierto la entrada para que tenga ese formato y luego parseo la fecha.

```
var parseDate = function(date){
  var parts = date.split('-');
  var temp = parts[0];
  parts[0] = parts[1];
  parts[1] = temp;
  return new Date(Date.parse(parts.join('/')));  
}

var sumDays = function(date, days){
  var fdate = parseDate(date);
  fdate.setDate(fdate.getDate()+days);
  return fdate;
}
```

Y para probar que funcione realmente:

```
sumDays("15-02-1981", 3);
//Te muestra en la consola
//Date 1981-02-18T05:00:00.000Z
```

Y:

```
sumDays("15-02-1981", 20);
//Date 1981-03-07T05:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Para añadir días puedes usar este método:

```
dias = 3;
fecha = new Date(); // ó new Date(valor);
fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + dias);
```

**Edit:** Si necesitas ingresar la fecha en un formato en específico, puedes usar la librería [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
dias = 3;
fecha = '15-02-1981'; // string
fechaMoment = moment(fecha,'DD-MM-YYYY').add(3, 'day');
```

Luego puedes transformar el objeto moment a un objeto Date:

```
fechaMoment.toDate(); // Wed Feb 18 1981 ...
```

O imprimirlo con formato:

```
fechaMoment.format('DD-MM-YYYY'); // 18-02-1981
```

Puedes leer más sobre como manipular fechas con moment en su [documentación](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: Gracias por contestar, en mi caso necesito sumar dias a una fecha en concreto que yo le paso y tiene el formato dd-mm-YYYY